# Pandas Groupby: 'observed' parameter with multiple categoricals

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider the following DataFrame with two categorical columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "state": pd.Categorical(["AK", "AL", "AK", "AL"]),
    "gender": pd.Categorical(["M", "M", "M", "F"]),
    "name": list("abcd"),
})
```

In `df.groupby()`, the default is `observed=False`.  The [description](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#handling-of-un-observed-categorical-values) for `observed` (Pandas 0.25.0) is:

> When using a Categorical grouper (as a single grouper, or as part of multiple groupers), the observed keyword controls whether to return a **cartesian product of all possible groupers values** (observed=False) or only those that are observed groupers (observed=True).

Accordingly, this is the result I would expect:

```
>>> # Expected result
>>> df.groupby(["state", "gender"])["name"].count()
state  gender
AK     M         2
       F         0
AL     F         1
       M         1
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

This is the actual result:

```
>>> df.groupby(["state", "gender"])["name"].count()
state  gender
AK     M         2
AL     F         1
       M         1
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Am I misinterpreting the description here?

This workaround seems like a huge pain and exactly what *should* be created by `observed=False`.  Am I missing an alternative?

```
>>> idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
...     (
...         df["state"].cat.categories,
...         df["gender"].cat.categories,
...     ),
...     names=["state", "gender"]
... )
>>> df.groupby(["state", "gender"])["name"].count().reindex(idx).fillna(0.).astype(int)
state  gender
AK     F         0
       M         2
AL     F         1
       M         1
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Looks like it's definitely a bug. Works fine with `DataFrameGroupBy.Count` but not with `SeriesGroupBy.Count`.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be a bug: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27075

Answer (score 5):

Seems like where you put `["name"]` is throwing it off. I think this works:

```
df.groupby(["state", "gender"]).count().fillna(0)["name"]
state  gender
AK     F         0.0
       M         2.0
AL     F         1.0
       M         1.0
Name: name, dtype: float64
```

Here are some useful variations:

```
In [16]: df.groupby(["state", "gender"], observed=False).count().fillna(0)["name"].astype(int)
Out[16]:
state  gender
AK     F         0
       M         2
AL     F         1
       M         1
Name: name, dtype: int64

In [17]: df.groupby(["state", "gender"], observed=True).count()["name"]
Out[17]:
state  gender
AK     M         2
AL     M         1
       F         1
Name: name, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is a better solution than my own. It is more explicit _and_ it retains the name.

Comment: This works, though I'd note that there's maybe a slight inefficiency: `.count().fillna(0)["name"]` computes counts for _all_ columns unnecessarily, rather than just 1.

Answer (score 4):

I am likewise uncertain about `observed`. However, the result you want is not so difficult to get. Tack on `.unstack(fill_value=0).stack()`.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     "state": pd.Categorical(["AK", "AL", "AK", "AL"]),
...     "gender": pd.Categorical(["M", "M", "M", "F"]),
...     "name": list("abcd"),
... }) 
>>> df.groupby(['state', 'gender'])['name'].count().unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
state  gender
AK     M         2
       F         0
AL     M         1
       F         1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: great answer. May I ask why did you put the observed?

Comment: @adhg Thank you. Ah, that was just an artifact of my tinkering. It does not affect the result -- I'll remove it, thanks.

Comment: oh, ok. I thought it had a meaning. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Using `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.state,df.gender).stack()
state  gender
AK     F         0
       M         2
AL     F         1
       M         1
dtype: int64
```